# Application of Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability

Suppose $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of non-negative random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbf{P})$, such that $\mathbf{E}X_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ and $\text{Var} X_n=c$ for all $n$. How can I use Chebyshev's inequality to prove that $\mathbf{P}(X_n>\alpha)\to 1$ as $n\to\infty$ for all $\alpha$?

Comment: Compare the events $[X_n\lt\alpha]$ and $[|X_n-E(X_n)|\gt\beta\sqrt{\text{Var}(X_n)}]$.

Comment: Do I have to set $\beta=(E(X_n)-\alpha)/\sqrt{\text{Var}(X_n)}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ fixed. We can write 
$$\mathbf P(X_n\leq \alpha)=\mathbf P(X_n-EX_n\leq \alpha-EX_n).$$
Since $\lim_{n\to +\infty}-EX_n=-\infty$, for $n$ large enough we have that $\alpha-EX_n<0$ hence 
$$\mathbf P(X_n\leq \alpha)=\mathbf P((X_n-EX_n)^2\geq (\alpha-EX_n)^2)$$
and by Chebyshev's inequality
$$\mathbf P(X_n\leq \alpha)\leq \frac c{(\alpha-EX_n)^2}$$
and we are done.

Comment: To make it clear that in the step where Xn-EXn is squared the inequality is reversed because both sides of the inequality are negative.